# When can one "bring in" Yom Kippur?

Tags: halacha, zemanim, yom-kippur

I've read in several places that one must bring in Yom Kippur before dark, just as we do for Shabbos. The time listed as the beginning of Yom Kippur (e.g. [MyZmanim](http://www.myzmanim.com)) seems to be 18 minutes before sunset (as is the custom for Shabbos).

That being the case, is one permitted to wait until past that time, and "go into the 18 minutes," before bringing in Yom Kippur as long as you bring in Yom Kippur within the 18 minutes (i.e., before sunset)?

Answer (score 2):

Qitzur Shulhhan Arukh, Yalqut Yosef ([Orahh Hayim 608:2](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_29.html#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9FB%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%97B-B%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8B%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94B%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%AA-%D7%91)) states (my translation including excerpt from Halakhah.com):

> צריך לסיים אכילתו ושתייתו מבעוד יום, כי מצוה מן התורה להוסיף מחול על הקודש, וכמו שדרשו חז''ל (יומא פא:) ועניתם את נפשותיכם בתשעה לחודש בערב, יכול משתחשך, תלמוד לומר בתשעה לחודש, הא כיצד מתחיל ומתענה מבעוד יום, מכאן שמוסיפים מחול על הקודש. [ש''ע סי' תרח ס''א] [...] וכן צריך לפרוש ממלאכה ומאיסורי שבות מבעוד יום, **מלפני שקיעת החמה**, **מעט או הרבה**. **וזמן התוספת הוא מעט קודם שקיעת החמה. ודי אפילו בכל שהוא מן התורה כל זמן שלא שקעה החמה**.
>
> One must finish eating and drinking while it is still daytime, because it is a Biblical commandment to add from the mundane unto the holy as HaZa"L exegeted ([Masekhet Yoma 81B](http://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Yoma.pdf)):
>
> > "And ye shall afflict your souls, in the ninth day of the month. One might have assumed that such affliction commences on the ninth of the month already. Therefore the text reads: ‘At even’. If from ‘at even’, one might have inferred that one must afflict oneself only after it gets dark, therefore the text reads: ‘In the ninth’. How is [this to be explained]? He should commence to afflict himself whilst it is yet day. From here we learn that we add from the profane time to the sacred one." (see Shulhhan Arukh, Orahh Hayim 608:1)
>
> Therefore, one should cease from *melakhah* and from *shevut* prohibitions while it is still daytime **(i.e. before sunset, either a short or long time). And the duration of the [addition from the mundane unto the holy] is a short time before sunset. And, Biblically speaking, any amount of time while the sun has not yet set is sufficient.**

Answer (score 1):

Yom Kippur comes in the same time as Shabbos does. If by Shabbos you can go into the eighteen minutes so too by Yom Kippur so as long as you add a little from before shkiah (at least 4 minutes) you can go into the eighteen minutes.

See Shulchan Aruch siman 608 seif 1 and Shulchan Aruch Harav there seif 1 -3 about Yom Kippur. Regarding Shabbos see Shulchan Aruch Harav siman 261 seif 4-5 –

Comment: Do not forget that Kol Nidrei **must** occur before skia because hatatras nedarim must occur during the day. THus, one must start Yom Kippur before that.

Comment: @saba why must hatarat nedarim happen during the day? Also what does that have to do with kol nidrei which probably isnt halachicly meaningful as a modaa for the future let alone hatarat nedarim? Also shouldn't you start yk after kol nidrei?

Comment: @skraz13 Shulchan Arukh haRav 608 says there is no minimum to the addition. He doesn't say 4 minutes anywhere that I see there.

Comment: your right its not brought in the shulchan aruch where he just explains the idea of tosefes shabbos (yom kippur) the source for the four minutes is based off the ravs siddur the ketzos hashulchan siman tzadik gimmul seif koton beis  explains that the minuimum time to add is four minutes  (the most leineint opinion is 2 minutes before shkiah see igros moshe orach chaim cheilek daled siman tzadik vov and piskei T'Shuvos siman reish samach aleph seif vov and note 67 - 68

Comment: @skraz13 Why do you keep telling me what the most lenient time is, when the other answer quotes Rav Ovadia Yosef as saying any amount is sufficient? Clearly that is the most lenient position!

Comment: if you notice it says min hatorah so yes bibicaly a few moments is enough however midirabanan i cant say for sure because i dont have those seforim and im saying this from memory but i beleive even acording to rav ovadia you need at least  two minutes (if i remember correctly it speaks about it in chazon ovadia Hilchos Shabbos cheilek aleph page 264 and yabia omer cheilek hey siman chof aleph) but again could be wrong